# jQuery Draggable Stop: function to stopPropagation of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am trying to get it so when the draggable element has stopped the two elements that I assign stopPropagation. Code I have so far, with no errors, yet not working.

```
 $( "#pop_up" ).draggable({ 
        handle: "#pop_header",
        containment: "parent", 
        stop:function(e) {
             if ($(e.target).attr('id') === "submit") {
               e.stopPropagation();
                return false;
            } 
          else if ($(e.target).attr('id') === "close")
           {
          e.stopPropagation();
           return false;
          }
      }
 });
```

Basic HTML mockup-

```
<div id="pop_up">
  <div id="pop_header">
    <span class="button" id="submit"></span>
    <span class="button" id="close"></span>
  </div>
     <div id="pop_body">

   </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas how to get these elements to become clickable as of right now they are not clickable like I tell my jQuery to do.-

```
$('.button #close').click(function() {
  $('#pop_up').hide();
 });
 $('.button #submit').click(function() {
      var miniVis = $('#minimize_wrapper').css('display');
  if(miniVis ==="block"){
       $('#minimize_wrapper').slideUp();
   } else {
      $('#minimize_wrapper').slideDown();
   }
  });
```

Comment: `$(.button #close)` does not worl, because you try to go a layer deeper. Just do `#close` and `#submit` for the buttons.

Comment: Ya know I had it in my JS like this - `.close#submit` not the space to go one element in further. My bad for that mistake above. I answered my own question anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so what I had to do was change the first code for draggable to this-

```
$( "#pop_up" ).draggable({ 
    handle: "#pop_header",
    containment: "parent", 
    stop:function(e) {
         if ($(e.target).attr('id') === "parent-of-buttons") {
           e.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        } 
    }
});
```

And then I changed the second code to this-

```
$('#parent-of-buttons').on('click','#close',function(){
  $('#pop_up').hide();
 });
$('#parent-of-buttons').on('click','#submit',function(){
     var miniVis = $('#minimize_wrapper').css('display');
 if(miniVis ==="block"){
   $('#minimize_wrapper').slideUp();
  } else {
   $('#minimize_wrapper').slideDown();
  }
});
```

Well hope this will help anyone else trying to do this. You can't stopPropagation of the buttons themselves but you can stopPropagation of that parent element.